# memory alignment issue in calloc() replacement?

Tags: c, embedded, heap-memory

Using below code I'm trying to write a wrapper for `calloc()` so that I can keep trace of allocated heap memory by storing the size in 1st 2/4bytes of the allocated memory. When I tested this alone seems its okay. But when I replace this as my system `calloc()` then its creating problems.. means some times its returning `NULL`, even though lot of heap available.

I'm running this on ARM board using IAR compiler:

```
void *MyCalloc(size_t size) {
    size_t new_size = ((size + 3) & ~0x3); 
    size_t *result = calloc(1,new_size + sizeof(size_t)); 
    if ( result ) { 
        printf("MyCalloc addr: %p\n", result);
        *result = (new_size + sizeof(size_t));
        result = result + sizeof(size_t);
    } 
return result;
}
```

Any idea why this is causing problem?

Comment: "Is this a compiler bug?" - "No, it's your code."

Comment: How are you replacing `calloc` ?

Comment: Last line should be restult = result + 1 ?

Comment: @LukaRahne yes, it should be.

Comment: @H2CO3 That's not very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. When writing heap functions, or heap wrappers, just don't use pointer arithmetic for storing heap headers. Use structures. That's what they're for.
2. You've introduced a number of integer overflow bugs into your code. If someone asks your `calloc()` for 0xfffffffe bytes, you'll return them 4 bytes. If they write more than 4 bytes to that allocation, there'll be a heap overflow.
3. Your `calloc()` doesn't have the same signature as `calloc()`. Depending on how you're swapping out `calloc()`, this is likely to become a problem.
4. `calloc()` and `malloc()` naturally return aligned pointers. In x86 they need to return a pointer to the application that is aligned to at least 8 bytes, and in x64 they need to return a pointer that is at least 16-byte aligned.

   In your code, you're using the real calloc to do the "heavy lifting" (i.e. as the "raw allocator"), which is fine and that will return an 8 or 16-byte aligned pointer, but when you return a pointer 4-bytes into that structure, your calloc ends up returning a non-aligned pointer to the caller, which is likely to cause problems to people calling your calloc replacement.

Try some code a bit more like this:

```
 typedef struct 
 {
    size_t cbSize;
 } MyAwesomeHeapHeader;
 // TODO: ensure that MyAwesomeHeapHeader is 8-byte aligned on x86 and 16-byte aligned on x64 (or just 16-byte aligned on both).

 void* MyAwesomeMalloc(size_t cbSize)
 {
    MyAwesomeHeapHeader* header;
    void* internalAllocatorPtr;
    size_t cbAlloc;
    // TODO: Maybe I want a heap footer as well?

    // TODO: I should really check the following for an integer overflow:
    cbAlloc = sizeof(MyAwesomeHeapHeader) + cbSize; 
    internalAllocatorPtr = MyAwesomeRawAllocator(cbAlloc); // at the moment you're using the real calloc for this, but you could use malloc or write your own raw allocator
    // TODO: Check for null

    header = (MyAwesomeHeapHeader*)internalAllocatorPtr;
    header->heapSize = cbSize;
    // TODO: other fields here.

    return (uint8_t*)(internalAllocatorPtr) + sizeof(MyAwesomeHeapHeader);
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is this line:

```
result = result + sizeof(size_t);
```

With pointer addition the number is implicitly multiplied by the size of of the pointer.  So

```
result = result + 1;
```

will move the result pointer ahead by `sizeof(size_t)` bytes.  Which is what you want. Because

```
result = result + sizeof(size_t);
```

moves the result pointer ahead by `sizeof(size_t) * sizeof(size_t)` bytes.

Because of this the `result` pointer is not pointing the the correct location, the calling code will overflow the end of the allocated buffer corrupting the heap.

Comment: I tried with *result++ = (new_size + sizeof(size_t)); and then return result; still doesn't work. for me when the values is 16bytes its working for once and immediate 16 bytes request returning NULL